# Is it possible to get the number of views and likes of a youtube video whithout using the YouTube data API?

Tags: python, youtube, kivy, kivy-language, pytube

I'm using kivy and pytube to build and app to get some information of any video of youtube just with its link, until now I'm able to get the thumbnail, title and download the video/audio file, but I really would like to implement more information such as the views and likes.

I've searched but almost all tutorials use many libraries or the API, it would be amazing if someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: Could you argue why are you running away from [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3)?

Answer (score 2):

To get views count pytube can be used, but pytube library does not have a built-in way to extract the likes count of a YouTube video

```
from pytube import YouTube

video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLWxivKA2Ow"

yt = YouTube(video_url)
print("Views:", yt.views)
```

Alternatively, you can use BeautifulSoup library for the same

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLWxivKA2Ow"
response = requests.get(video_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
views = soup.find("div", class_="watch-view-count").text
likes = soup.find("button", class_="like-button-renderer-like-button").text

print("Views:", views)
print("Likes:", likes)
```